# xsd import from xsd include

Tags: xsd, lxml, libxml2, xmllint, xsd-1.1

I'm having the following "imp.xsd":

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://imported"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Imported" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

*imported* from "incl.xsd":

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://main"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://imported" schemaLocation="file:///C:/.../imp.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="Included" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

which in turn is *included* from "main.xsd":

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://main"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="file:///C:/.../incl.xsd"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="dummy">
        <xsd:sequence xmlns:impt="http://imported" xmlns:incl="http://main">
            <xsd:element ref="incl:Included"/>
            <xsd:element ref="impt:Imported"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Question:** is "main.xsd" a valid xml schema document?

When validated with the `xmllint` parser (or from python `lxml` library, which in turn uses xmllint), I get the following error:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref':
>   References from this schema to components in the namespace
>   'http://imported' are not allowed, since not indicated by an import
>   statement. WXS schema main.xsd failed to compile

However, another (IBM) parser accepts this XSD without any complaints.

As far as I understand xsd:include, it should behave as if the whole included XSD is inlined into the main document. So, in my opinion, the "main.xsd" should be valid. Is it?

**Edit:** I was experimenting with `xmllint` a bit, and when I add the line

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://imported" schemaLocation="file:///C:/.../imp.xsd"/>
```

into "main.xsd", xmllint accepts that schema. However, when I add the same line while omitting `file:///`, I get the following warning:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Skipping import of
>   schema located at 'C:/.../imported.xsd' for the namespace
>   'http://imported', since this namespace was already imported with the
>   schema located at 'file:///V:/.../imported.xsd'.

Hence I deduce that the original "main.xsd" is valid and that this is a bug in `xmllint`.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2004Jul/0006.html) on the xmlschema-dev@w3.org mailing list. In his answer, Henry S. Thompson quotes following part of [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/PER-xmlschema-1-20040318/#src-resolve):

> For a ·QName· to resolve to a schema component [...] the
>   ·namespace name· of the ·QName· is the same as one of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - The ·actual value· of the namespace [attribute] of some <import>
>      element information item contained in the <schema> element
>      information item **of that schema document** [emphasis added].

So indirect imports are not supposed to work.